# CSS Social icons not visible

Tags: html, css

When I try to add social icons they show up like this:
[Blue Squares (effect I have on the buttons above shows up instead of social icons)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diBYC.png)

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parallax"></div>
    <h1>
    </h1>
    </div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Century Gothic;">Najnovije od Logitech-a</span> </h1>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="#" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Logitech G Pro X Superlight, Cijena: 239.99 KM <br> <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Bosanski</a>
                <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Engleski</a>
                </br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="#" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Logitech G733 LightSpeed, Cijena: 329.99 KM <br> <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Bosanski</a>
                <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Engleski</a>
                </br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerdesno">
        <img src="#" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Logitech G333, Cijena: 79.99 KM <br> <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Bosanski</a>
                <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Engleski</a>
                </br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerdesno">
        <img src="#" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Logitech G Pro Keyboard K/DA Edition, Cijena: 209.99 KM <br> <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Bosanski</a>
                <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Engleski</a>
                </br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "footer">
        <div class= "footer-content">
            <div class = "footer-section about">
                <p>
                    Ovlastena Logitech prodavnica u BiH. 
                </p>
                <div class= "contact">
                    <span><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> &nbsp; +41 (0)21 863 55 11
                    <span><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> &nbsp; support@logitech.ba
                </div>
                <div class= "socials">
                    <a href= "#"><i class = "fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href= "#"><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href= "#"><i class = "fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class= "footer-bottom">
            Designed by Anes Tarić
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parallax {
    background-image: url("#");
    min-height: 1000px;
    /* Efekat na stranici */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


/* Dodatni efekti i slike za bolji izgled stranice :) */

.rectangle {
    height: 200px;
    width: 1920px;
    background-color: #555;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.containerdesno {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    left: 1000px;
    top: -1427px;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.containerdesno:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

a {
    display: inline-flex
}

a {
    background-color: #00ccff;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

a:active {
    background-color: black;
}

.footer {
    background: #303036;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

.footer .footer-bottom {
    background: #343a40;
    color: #686868;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

.footer .footer-content {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 450px;
    display: flex;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Idk how does this even happen, I made a new footer and yet it still has the same effect as the buttons above. I tried fixing it but it just made it worse, any help would be appreciated :)

edit: sorry for my messy code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the links show up as blue rectangles is because you've said that all links everywhere should have blue background and white "text":

```
a {
    display: inline-flex
}

a {
    background-color: #00ccff;
    color: white;
    /* ... */
}
```

If you don't want this treatment for the things in the footer, make these selectors more specific, perhaps changing them to `.text a` ("all links inside an element with class `text`").

For the icons themselves not showing up: there may be errors in the developer console (F12 key) that give a clue. For example, I would not expect the `<link>` tag to have `href="stylesheet"`; that probably needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your CDN doesn't have the fab icons. try using this CDN instead.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wESLQ85D6gbsF459vf1CiZ2+rr+CsxRY0RpiF1tLlQpDnAgg6rwdsUF1+Ics2bni" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or

Download the started kit from https://fontawesome.com/ and install it locally. they also have proper documentation for that.